# How to load JSON response on each rows input fields

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I am novice in Programming and searching answer for the below problem in this site over days but couldn’t figure anything yet.

Firstly, A input form will prompt to the user, then the user will define how many rows there will be. 
Then in the HTML table, each rows has 3 input fields(ID, Name, Number).
When a user gives an ID, the name and number of that ID will be placed in the next input fields of that row. For better understanding I am attaching an img.
[demo_img.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QUJnz.png)

**studentInfo.php** page, Ajax response will set here:

```
<form class="" action="" method="POST">
 <?php
   $count = $_REQUEST["countID"]; //<--get the number from the user
   for($i=1; $i<=$count; $i++){
 ?>
 <tr>
   <td>
     <input type="number" name="id[]" class="id">
   </td>
   <td>
     <input type="text" name="fname[]" class="fname">
   </td>
   <td>
     <input type="number" name="num[]" class="num">
   </td>
 </tr>
 <?php
   }
 ?>
</form>
```

The Ajax portion:

```
$(".id").change(function(){
  var sid = $(this).val();
  $.ajax({
    method: "GET",
    url: "getData.php",
    data: {sid: sid},
    dataType: "json",
    success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR){
      if(data.length == 0){
        alert("No data found");
      } else {
        // I am stuck here. If I console.log(data) the JSON format coming from getData.php is showing like this: {name: 'JACKS DONUTS', num: '185'}
      }
    },
    error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
      //Show the error msg
    }
  });
});
```

Now, How do I set the result to the input fields.
Any suggestion in my code will be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: `id` attributes **must** be unique so adding multiple elements in the loop violates that uniqueness principle and any javascript code that relies upon `id`s will fail

Comment: Your SQL is vulnerable to SQL Injection because of the use of request variables being used directly rather than using a prepared statement with bound parameters.

Comment: Your HTML is invalid- there are no `table` element tags so you cannot simply add table-rows to a form

Comment: Remove the duplicate IDs, and work with class names instead. Use the relationship the elements have in the DOM, to find the correct input fields you need to populate - from the current element that your event occurred on, go up to the parent `tr` element (`parents()` method), and then find the input fields within that one using their class (using `find()`).

Comment: Can you print response what u get when u do echo json_encode($result);

Comment: @ProfessorAbronsius Great observation. Some how I missed that out. As for now I don't need the ID attribute, so I will remove that. And in future if I need ID attribute, then I will append the ID with my counter variable-'i' like this:
<?php echo "<input type="number" name="id[]" id="id$i" class="id">"; ?>

Comment: @ProfessorAbronsius I found out on google that, in PHP **"mysqli_real_escape_string()"** function can sanitize the input, which will avoid the SQL injection. So I am going to use this function.

Comment: @Jaymin The JSON preview is like this:  
{name: "JACKS DONUTS", num: "185"}

Comment: **Warning:** You are wide open to [SQL Injections](https://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php) and should use parameterized **prepared statements** instead of manually building your queries. They are provided by [PDO](https://php.net/manual/pdo.prepared-statements.php) or by [MySQLi](https://php.net/manual/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php). Never trust any kind of input! Even when your queries are executed only by trusted users, [you are still in risk of corrupting your data](http://bobby-tables.com/). [Escaping is not enough!](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32391315)

Comment: @CBroe Your idea helps me, Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Your requirement can be achieve by post an array of IDs to an URL e.g. ***getData.php*** using *ajax*.

```
['1001', '1002', '1003']
```

Then the ***getData.php*** will return an array of student data with ID as key.

```
{
  "1001": {
    "name": "Student A",
    "number": 20
  },
  "1002": {
    "name": "Student B",
    "number": 21
  },
  "1003": {
    "name": "Student C",
    "number": 23
  }
}
```

Once you retrieved the student data, try to look for the student data by using the input ID as key, if the data exists, append the data to the form.

```
if (data[inputId]) {
    const studentData = data[inputId];
    /* following methods will find input with class name and set the input value with given value */
    setValue('name', studentData.name);
    setValue('number', studentData.number);
}
```

Following is the **SAMPLE** by post the IDs to an API placeholder URL and **SIMULATE** the return data:

```js
/* bind click event to buttons */
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#add-row").click(addRow);
  $("#get-data").click(getData);
});

/* add extra row for input ID */
function addRow() {
  $rowHtml = `
    <tr class="student-data">
      <td><input type="text" class="id" name="id[]" /></td>
      <td><input type="text" class="name" /></td>
      <td><input type="text" class="number" /></td>
    </tr>
  `;

  $("#form-table").append($rowHtml);
}

/* get data when user submit */
function getData() {
  const fieldset = $('#fieldset')
  const message = $('#message')
  const inputs = $(`input[name="id[]"]`)

  /* get multiple ids as array where which by the user */
  const ids = inputs.toArray().map(function(input) {
    return input.value
  })

  /* store ids in a data object */
  const dataToSubmit = {
    ids: ids
  }

  /* url to post to submit the data e.g. "getData.php" */
  /* following is just a demo url */
  const url = "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts"

  $.ajax({
    method: "POST",
    url: url,
    data: dataToSubmit,
    dataType: "json",
    beforeSend: function() {
      /* disable the form when submitting */
      fieldset.prop("disabled", true);
      message.html('Getting data...');
    },
    success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
      /* your data should return an array of objects with the key is the id */
      /* e.g. {1001: {name: "Student A", number: 20}, 1002: {name: "Student B", number: 21},…} */

      /* THIS IS NOT PART OF THE CODE! this is just a simulation of fetching the data */
      data = JSON.parse(`{"1001":{"name":"Student A","number":20},"1002":{"name":"Student B","number":21},"1003":{"name":"Student C","number":23}}`);

      /* fill the student data once retrieved data  */
      fillStudentData(data);
    },
    complete: function() {
      /* enable back the form after form was submitted */
      fieldset.prop("disabled", false);
      message.html('');
    }
  });
}

function fillStudentData(data) {
  $('.student-data').each(function() {
    /* get the id by find the input with "id" class */
    const inputId = $(this).children().find(".id")[0].value;

    /* get student data using id key */
    const studentData = data[inputId];

    /* set the name and number if there is data found */
    if (studentData) {
      /* this function will find the inputs in "student-data" class and filled the input with value */
      const setValue = (className, value) => {
        $(this).children().find("." + className)[0].value = value;
      };

      setValue('name', studentData.name);
      setValue('number', studentData.number);
    }
  })
}
```

```html
<form style="display: flex;">
  <fieldset id="fieldset">
    <table id="form-table" border="1" cellpadding="10">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>ID</th>
          <th>Name</th>
          <th>Number</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr class="student-data">
          <td><input type="text" class="id" name="id[]" /></td>
          <td><input type="text" class="name" /></td>
          <td><input type="text" class="number" /></td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
    <span>Sample ID: 1001, 1002, 1003</span>
    <button type="button" id="add-row">Add Row</button>
    <button type="button" id="get-data">Get Data</button>
    <span id="message"></span>
  </fieldset>
</form>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```